# hash for membership in ruby?

Tags: ruby, hash

Is there a hash mechanism in Ruby where you can quickly test for membership but not necessarily be able to enumerate the members?

For example, I want to do something like:

```
members = MembershipHash.new
members << 10
members << 28

members.include? 10
# returns true

members.include? 88
# returns false
```

I'd like it to be a string representation, so if I have 1M entries, i don't need the overhead of storing 1M entries, like an array.  Kind of like Digest::SHA256.hexdigest, but where you could query it to see if a particular value is in it.

Is there anything like this in ruby?

Thanks for any help,
kevin

UPDATE- adding additional info based on comments

I'm thinking of something like the following

```
digest = f(a)
digest = f(a,digest)
digest = f(b,digest)
digest = f(c,digest)

digest.include? c
```

The idea is, could you determine whether the digest could have an item in it's ancestry. Kind of a blockchain like thing, but I really just need it to test for membership quickly without doing a linear search of the set of members.  I'm thinking of a ring or an elliptic curve, I feel like there must be some construct out there that does this, maybe if anyone knows the term for this it would help make a solution searchable with google or something.  Thanks for your comments so far.

Comment: and may I ask, why do you need this do in ruby first of all? why don't use any rdbms or non-relational db?

Answer (score 2):

I believe ruby sets fit the case

```
irb(main):008:0> require 'set'
=> false
irb(main):009:0> members = Set.new
=> #<Set: {}>
irb(main):010:0> members << 10
irb(main):011:0> members << 28
=> #<Set: {10, 28}>
irb(main):012:0> members.include? 10
=> true
```

Comment: have a look at this simple guide of using sets https://dev.to/shahershamroukh/ruby-sets-1b55

Answer (score 0):

> I don't need the overhead of storing 1M entries

It's impossible to "test for membership" without storing the members. (How would the test work??)

You may be able to save memory by using e.g. `Digest::SHA256.hexdigest`, as you suggest, but this only makes sense if the members are very large (e.g. image files), not small (e.g. the two examples you actually gave, of the numbers `10` and `28`):

```
Digest::SHA256.hexdigest('28')
=> "59e19706d51d39f66711c2653cd7eb1291c94d9b55eb14bda74ce4dc636d015a"
```

There is no built-in ruby library to automatically do this for you, but it's a fairly straightforward to do manually, e.g.

```
require 'set'
member_shas = Set.new
member_shas << Digest::SHA256.hexdigest(big_data_1)
member_shas << Digest::SHA256.hexdigest(big_data_2)

# ...

members.include? Digest::SHA256.hexdigest(thing_to_check)
```

...Or you could create your own class to do this `Digest::SHA256.hexdigest` conversion automatically, by defining your own `<<` and `include?` methods.

You could also consider using a database, instead.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts. I believe "storing membership" and "testing for membership" are not the same complexity.  I think something like a cyclical redundancy check is something similar but not exactly what I need.  The idea is "could this digest possibly have come from n digests, one of which was x.  That would be a test for membership.  This is what I'm looking for.